# Difference between these similar Edify commands to mount and unmount

Tags: android, shell, mount, unmount, edify

I made a custom boot animation for my Android smartphone running Android 9 (Pie) and since my phone is not rooted it appears the only way to install the animation is through a flashable zip.
Inside this zip file, other than the files to install themselves, there is a file called *updater-script* which contains the instructions to install the content of the flashable zip.
Now, I learned that in order to extract the boot animation into its directory, the filesystem needs to be mounted, and then unmounted.
After this brief introduction, here is the actual question: there are at least three different ways to do so. What is the difference between:

- `run_program("/sbin/mount", "/system");`
- `run_program("/sbin/busybox", "mount", "/system");`
- `mount("ext4", "EMMC", "/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system", "/system");`

?
And which is the correct one to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I went with solution #2 because #3 didn't work.